# How to gain access to out of scope variable in php?

Tags: php, scope, counter

I have a function in a loop:

```
for ($i=1; $i<=10; $i++) {
    Route::get('/projects/oop/'.$i, function(){
        return View::make('projects.oop'. $i); <--- This line give me a problem.
    });
};
```

I keep getting:

> i is not defined.

How will I fix it so I can have the access to my `$i` variable?

Comment: `PHP` is not `Javascript`. You [cannot concatenate strings using `+` in `PHP`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.useful-funcs).

Comment: I fixed it. Thanks. I got confused for a bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not the proper way to handle dynamic route paths in laravel.

What you need to do is remove that nasty `for` loop all together, then you need to pass a dynamic value as the 3rd argument to this Route.

```
Route::get('/projects/oop/{id}, 'ProjectsController@oop');
```

Now, you need to go to your controllers directory and make a controller called:

```
class ProjectsController extends BaseController {
    function oop($id){
        return View::make('projects.oop.'.$id);
    }
}
```

Now your route will properly pass the request to the ProjectsController class, which will then imeplement the oop function and pass the {id} from the Route to the function as an argument.

Comment: I think that `$id` will always be "set" in your example wouldn't it? In my experience better to leave `$id` without a default value and then check `is_null($is)`.

Comment: @JakeWilson You may be entirely right about that point, as without having an ID at the end of the route, that route would not resolve in any event. I will adjust my conditional to reflect this.